# Simple Page Redirect Using URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect

I want my index.php to redirect to my welcome/index.html. I know there are so many ways to do it but I want to shorten it just like Facebook does. I want a url based redirection. I want to redirect index.php to welcome/index.html by using url.

For example:

```
example.com to example.com/?url=welcome
//this 'url=welcome' is the index.html of my welcome folder.
```

Comment: remove inappropriate tags, facebook etc

Comment: noted @gouravbajaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somewhere i read using header for redirection is little bit dangerous as header can b changed easily by hacker and hacker can send victim to another location easily. so i use javascript   **location.href** function for redirection.

```
<?php
echo "<script>window.location ='http://example.com/welcome/index.html</script>";
?>
```

if you want to send user to dynamic url from example.com you can set a get variable like.

source address: http//example.com?url=http://example.com/welcome.html
destination address: http://example.com/welcome.html

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['url']))
echo "<script>window.location ='$_GET[url]'</script>";
else
echo "<script>window.location='http://somewhereelse.com'";
?>
```

now u can dynamically set url variable in your source address and redirect user wherever you want to

Comment: how can I do that @gourav-bajaj

Comment: I want to shorten it as possible like after 6 seconds ?url=welcome will appear instead of example.com/welcome/

Comment: Provide the link to this "somewhere I read" and what makes using javascript better or even more secure?

Comment: I dont get it? Please make your comment more understandable

Comment: please tell what you didn't get?

Comment: can you make it more easy

Comment: this line  

source address: http//example.com?url=http://example.com/welcome.html destination address: http://example.com/welcome.html

Comment: suppose example.com/index.php is the page from where you want to redirect. and example.com/welcome/index.html is your landing page. 

So in your index.php page you need to have variable like http://example.com/index.php?url=http://example.com/welcome/index.html 
so that whenever user come to index.php page will be redirect to welcome/index.html page. 

**Note :** For increase more security you can validate your domain before redirection

Comment: noted but i want to shorten it @gouravbajaj... like (http://example.com/index.php?url=welcome) instead of (http://index.php?url=http://example.com/welcome/index.html) after 6 seconds delay. **Also**: how can I validate my domain before redirection?

Comment: in that case, change your index.php 

if($_GET['url']==="welcome")
echo "<script>'http://example.com/welcome/index.php'</script>";

Comment: wait I dont understand it yet please elaborate further

Comment: noted again but I want to shorten it! your previous comment satisfies my question @gouravbajaj... I just dont know how to redirect using the ?url thing

Comment: delete everything and write code below.

http://example.com?url=welcome from where you wan to redirect right?

now in index.php write
if($_GET['url']==="welcome")
echo "<script>'http://example.com/welcome/index.html'</script>"

now whenever user visit page example.com?url=welcome will be redirect to http://example.com/welcome/index.html

Comment: right. but I want to display the **example.com?url=welcome** in the address bar not **example.com/welcome/index.html** @gouravbajaj

Comment: then? after googling?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code, according to what I've understood. Place it on the very top of `index.php`. I'm assuming you're using the domain `example.com`

```
<?php 

$destination = $_GET["url"];

switch($destination) {
    case "welcome": // add your destinations here, one per single "case"
    case "about":
    case "anotherpage":
        header("Location: /" . $destination . "/index.html");
    break;   
    default:
        echo "Error";
    break;
}

?>
```

Doing this way you can manage which redirects will work and what not, avoinding "evil" usages of your redirect system.

Something malicious like `example.com?url=http://evilsite.com` will not redirect them to `evilsite.com`

This is probably not the best solution, but it's a good starting point to avoid not wanted redirections.

Comment: also I would like to hide .html extension in index.html @Napolux

Comment: But it doesn't actually answer my question @napolux...should I use javascript instead like after 6 seconds it will redirect to welcome/index.html but the only thing u can see in the address bar is ?url=welcome

Comment: Do you want a JS solution or a PHP solution. At this point the question is not clear :(

Comment: Either one of them is sufficient as long as the output on the browser's address bar will be ?url=welcome

Comment: Either one of them is sufficient as long as the output on the browser's address bar will be ?url=welcome – @Napolux

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this would help, but you're welcome to try

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_GET["url"])) {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    header('Location:'.$url);
  }
 ?>
```

I haven't tried this, but this is what I thought after seeing your post

Comment: This is really dangerous as I can trick users to redirect them to something bad. Example:  `example.com?url=http://evilsite.com` will redirect them to `evilsite.com`

Comment: It's true, but as OP said in the title, a simple redirect. This will redirect in a very simple way

Comment: I would not advocate possible dangerous solutions, but of course this will also work. :-/

Comment: wait! Should I declare the $url?

Comment: You can use this as it is. But as @Napolux said, this is a very dangerous way of redirection, proof are the down votes I'm receiving

Comment: You could of course "clean" or limit the urls that will be used. You could instead use POST, but based from your example, you are using GET

Comment: how can I use POST? @carl-jan

Comment: wait Im so excited @CarlJan how can I use post?

Comment: @ChevroletSS Forgot to ask, what will be the final format of the URL?

Comment: Just like facebook uses @CarlJan facebook.com/?_rdr

Comment: @CarlJan the final format of the url will be e.g example.com/?url=welcome

Comment: Ahh, if so, then I don't think my answer will help you.

Comment: Why so? POST is somehow helpful. Just don't know how to use it